# How can I move an object over linerenderer lines positions?

Tags: unity, c#

I have 4 cubes the first 3 cubes connected with two lines one of the lines is curved. The fourth cube I want to move over the lines. The lines is built using linerenderer and in the linerenderer there are 397 positions. I created a small script that move an object over the positions. I checked and I have in the array 397 positions and the loop get to 397 but the object (Cube (3)) never moving all the positions only some. Or maybe the positions I get are not the same in the linerenderer ?

This screenshot show some of the positions in the linerenderer this is the positions I want the object to move on :

[image: Some positions from the linerenderer]

Why the object is not moving over all the positions , only on some ?
And this is the script I created that should move it :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveOnCurvedLine : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public GameObject objectToMove;
    public float speed;

    private Vector3[] positions = new Vector3[397];
    private Vector3[] pos;
    private int index = 0;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        pos = GetLinePointsInWorldSpace();
    }

    Vector3[] GetLinePointsInWorldSpace()
    {
        //Get the positions which are shown in the inspector 
        var numberOfPositions = lineRenderer.GetPositions(positions);
        //Iterate through all points, and transform them to world space
        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfPositions; i += 1)
        {
            positions[i] = transform.TransformPoint(positions[i]);
        }

        //the points returned are in world space
        return positions;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(index <= pos.Length - 1)
        {
            objectToMove.transform.position += pos[index] * Time.deltaTime * speed;
            index++;
        } 
    }
}
```

Now I checked using a breakpoint the first position in the linerender at index 0 is : X = 30.57, Y = -6.467235, Z = 4.98

But in my script in the pos array I see that in index 0 the position is :

X = 30.6, Y = -6.5, Z = 5.0

And the result is that the object that move Cube(3) is moving only some of the way and also it's not exactly on the line :

[image: Moving object has moved only some of the way]

Why the object is not moving over all the positions , only on some ?

Something is wrong in my script with getting the right positions from the linerenderer and maybe also the loop and the move is wrong. I can't figure out ho to do it.

Comment: Did you check that `pos[index]` actually contains an expected position? Do you use physics to control the object?

Comment: @Vaillancourt You right the positions in my array pos are not the same as in the linerenderer maybe because I'm converting them to world positions in my script ? Is that a reason why it will not work ?

Answer (score 1):

Working script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveOnCurvedLine : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public GameObject objectToMove;
    public float speed;

    private Vector3[] positions = new Vector3[397];
    private Vector3[] pos;
    private int index = 0;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        pos = GetLinePointsInWorldSpace();
        objectToMove.transform.position = pos[index];
    }

    Vector3[] GetLinePointsInWorldSpace()
    {
        //Get the positions which are shown in the inspector 
        lineRenderer.GetPositions(positions);
        
        //the points returned are in world space
        return positions;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Move();
    }

    void Move()
    {
        objectToMove.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(objectToMove.transform.position,
                                                pos[index],
                                                speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (objectToMove.transform.position == pos[index])
        {
            index += 1;
        }

        if (index == pos.Length)
            index = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained what you changed and why that solves the problem.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer as Accepted if it worked for you